# i don't understand what's happening with this code

Tags: javascript

You are given an array of positive integers. While the array has more than one element you can choose two elements and replace them with their sum or product.

Your task is to find the maximum possible number that can remain in the array after multiple such operations.

**Example**
For arr = [1, 3, 2], the result should be 9.

in order to maximize the answer the first operation will be 1 + 2 (the array changes into [3, 3]) and the next 3 * 3 (the array changes into [9]), so the final result is 9.

```
function sumOrProduct(arr) {
  if(arr.length == 1) return arr[0];
     arr = arr.sort();
  if(arr[0] == 1){
    if(arr.indexOf(2) == -1) arr.push(arr.shift() + arr.shift())
  else arr.push(arr.shift() + arr.splice(arr.indexOf(2),1)[0])
 }else arr.push(arr.shift() * arr.shift())
  return sumOrProduct(arr)
}
```

i don't understand this part and why is he using shift method there.

```
if(arr[0] == 1){
if(arr.indexOf(2) == -1) arr.push(arr.shift() + arr.shift())
else arr.push(arr.shift() + arr.splice(arr.indexOf(2),1)[0])
}else arr.push(arr.shift() * arr.shift())
```

Comment: If the array length isn't defined, this is more of a math problem than a programing problem since it is not that easy to determine all possibilities event with bruteforce-like methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question, but it seems that the solution is to `if there's 1, add it to the next lowest number, then multiply all the others`

```js
function sumOrProduct(arr){
  arr.sort((a,b)=>a-b)
  var num=arr[0]
  for(let i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(num==1){num+=arr[i]}
    else{num*=arr[i]}
  }
  return num||0
}

console.log( sumOrProduct([1,2,3]) )
console.log( sumOrProduct([1,3,2]) )
console.log( sumOrProduct([1,5,3,2,4]) )
```

What the shifting does, it loops through the array with custom start point(like a `for loop`), except it doesnt use a `for loop` and uses recursion and shifting to take out values from the array so that the same number isn't processed. As to why that complication was done instead of using a for loop? I think the person hates for loops ;-;